# Click CheckBox or Image in WebView to open a new Android Activity

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have created a `webview` that contains a `checkbox` and an `image`. I need to be able to check the `checkbox` or click on the `image` in the `webview` to open a new `activity`. For example if I click the `checkbox` or `image` in `screen1.html` it must load `Screen2Activity.java` which will display the second `webview` `screen2.html`.

#### screen1.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-align:center;
        }
        header{
            color: white;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 38pt;
            text-align:center;
        }
        subhead {
            color:red;
            background-color: black;
            font-family:verdana;
            font-size: 28pt;
            text-align:center;
        }
        normal {
            color: white;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 11pt;
            text-align:center;
            border: 1px white;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Screen1</header>
    <subhead>TYPE OF PROBLEM</subhead>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <normal>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"> Is this to do with you witnessing other people harming other people?
    <br>
    (OTHERS TO OTHERS) goto Y
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image1.gif" title="Home" width=200pt height=200pt /></a>
    <br><br><br><br><br>


    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">Is this to do with yourself affecting others?
    <br>
    (SELF TO OTHERS) goto X
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image11.gif" title="Home" width=200pt height=200pt /></a>
    <br><br><br><br><br>


    <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3"> Is this to do with yourself only?
    <br>
    (SELF TO SELF) goto Z
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image20.gif" title="Home" width="140" height="109" /></a>
    <br><br><br><br><br>


    <input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4"> Is this to do with someone (others) affecting you?
    <br>
    (OTHERS TO SELF)
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image22.gif" title="Home" width="140" height="109" /></a>
    <br><br><br><br><br>


    <input type="checkbox" name="5" value="5"> Is this to do with a Force affecting yourself?
    <br>
    (FORCES TO SELF)
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image16.gif" title="Home" width="140" height="109" /></a>
    <br><br><br><br><br>

    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main"> Main menu
    <br><br>
    <a href="screen2.html"><img src="image4.gif" title="Home" width="140" height="109" /></a>
    </normal>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Screen1Actvity.java

```
package com.example.warre.finalappwritings;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Screen1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/screen1.html");

    startService(new Intent(Screen1Activity.this, SoundService.class));
}

@Override
protected  void onStop(){
    stopService(new Intent(Screen1Activity.this, SoundService.class));
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    startService(new Intent(Screen1Activity.this, SoundService.class));
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method with Javascript

On HTML side:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
}
</script>
```

On native:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: How would this load the webview and this is showing a toast not going to a new activity?

Comment: You miss the key point. This is just an example for how trigger a method from Javascript. You can start an activity or anything you want. Change method name an write your startActivity codes into method.

Also you can find different explanion from here:  http://hongchaozhang.github.io/GitBlogs/code/2015/07/28/Communication-between-WebView-and-native-android.html#javascript_return_value_to_java